# Using cloudflare flexible ssl option causes login form to refresh instead of sending request

Tags: apache, laravel, ssl, cloudflare

I am using cloudflare's "flexible ssl" as an intermediary between client and my site.

After setting this up, I went to the browser and tried accessing my site via https:

`https://example.com/login`

and everything works. I fill in my login info and log in successfully and am not on `http://example.com` . I manually enter `https://example.com/*` where * is many other pages and it all works fine.

Now I want to redirect all requests to use the seemingly working https. So i go to my cloudflare account on their website and create a page rule : `http://example.com/*` to always use https.

Now I go to `example.com/login` and successfully redirected to `https://example.com/login`, I fill in my log in information and submit the login form , the page refreshes and I am back to `https://example.com/login` with an empty login form.

Anyone know what the problem is or how to help troubleshoot?

I am using laravel as a framework for the site and apache as the webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> create a page rule : http://example.com/* to always use https

Noted.  Be aware that CloudFlare does this by accepting every HTTP request on http://example.com/* and returning a 301 redirect to the equivalent HTTPS request.  The browser completes the redirect by sending a GET request to the HTTPS URL.

> I fill in my log in information and submit the login form

Check the login form source carefully and check what URL the login form is submitted to.  My guess is that the form is submitted to http://example.com/login or something similar. CloudFlare will accept the POST request to http://example.com/login and return a 301 redirect to https://example.com/login -- which your browser will complete as a GET request and hence not sending the login data.

So your best solution is to make sure that your login form POSTs to the correct HTTPS URL not to the HTTP URL.

That's my best guess anyway.

> how to help troubleshoot?

Ensure that you are using different log files to distinguish between HTTP and HTTPS requests on your server.

Some other suggestions:

- Get a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate and put that on your site so that the communication between CloudFlare and your site is all SSL.  https://letsencrypt.org/
- Ensure that HSTS is turned on for all of your HTTPS requests so that the browser will know not to send any requests to any HTTP URLs.
- Create a development server where you can test all of this working with HTTPS between the browser and the web server without CloudFlare.  Once you've got it all working in HTTPS mode without CloudFlare then you can try it with CloudFlare and you should get essentially the same results.  Your problem is with the HTTP -> HTTPS switch, not specifically with CloudFlare.